# Webpage displayed in Incognito, not in regular Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, incognito-mode

So i have been running into this problem with a lot of Wordpress sites lately, usually occurring when i am logged in as Admin, so i couldn't post here because no one would be able to view the problem.  However, i just found a site that it happens on that doesn't require admin creds.

```
http://www.otisports.com/
```

When i visit this site in Chrome (Version 34.0.1847.137 m), it just displays a blank page.  No errors, just the (what now seems standard) `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.` warning.  I have seen that warning signify problems on the site, but they are usually minor, not to the extent that the above URL displays.  However, if i open an Incognito window and visit the site everything works perfectly and there is no warning.  Does the Incognito window deal with webpages in a way that is so entirely different that it would cause something like this to happen?

I have been racking my brain trying to figure this out.  Can anyone reproduce this? is it a bug in chrome?

EDIT:  I just tried to open a bounty on this question and the EXACT same thing happened.  In Regular Chrome, nothing happened when i clicked the `start a bounty` link and i saw various errors `Undefined is not a function` however in incognito everything worked perfectly. what gives?!

EDIT:  Yes, i have cleared the cache, history, cookies, everything, and i still get the same errors.  I cant even post a comment on this question because of errors...

Comment: The only difference between the two versions of Chrome stated; is Cached JavaScript files.

Comment: Have you tried clearing all Chrome's caches?

Comment: i can view both in incognito as well as normal mode in chrome

Comment: Then maybe it's the version of WordPress (and it's respected JavaScript library that's being loaded; e.g. Outdated jQuery) is the issue; although these 'warnings' **won't** kill the execution of the page. For which, these would be PHP errors, invisible without `WP_DEBUG` being on.

Comment: If you can't post comment here on SO, you might have some kind of  malware script injection

Comment: @Misiur some Google extensions failing behind the scenes also come to mind (Although these are within iframes/own windows I suspect?)

Comment: Have you used CCleaner @celeriko "Open up extensions, Adblock Plus filters, Untick any filters you use, tick them again! 
"<--- this was one of solutions in google forum

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After reading the comments I dug into chrome and saw there was a bunch of extensions still sitting around that were definitely malware and I thought I had previously deleted.  Instead of picking through them one-by-one, I just deleted everything, re-installed Chrome, and now everything works great!

Comment: Really this 'answer' is a workaround. I have noticed Ghostery, which is not malware, can interfere with normal website functionality.  So, first thing to do is disable Ghostery for a site or sift through all the bugs it is blocking.

Comment: I've been looking for the answer, and IT WORKED. The very same solution. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 38):

I came across the same issue when trying to open evernote.com. It loaded successfully while using incognito mode in chrome. Let me share how I fixed this even though the original post is way too old. But maybe someone can find it useful.

I'm using chrome (Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)) running on Linux Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

I tried disabling all extensions and clearing browser data/cache but nothing worked. PS: Disabling adblock previously worked for me. Yes, I stumbled over the same issue before and whitelisting evernote in adblock solved the issue. But it didn't now.

The following is what worked for me:

1. Open developers tools (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>).
2. Navigate to `Applications` tab.
3. Choose `Storage` from the side menu
4. Hit `Clear site data` button.

Comment: This worked for me on Google Sheets, when I was stuck with a `Still working...` banner on any sheet that I opened.

Comment: WOW, thank you so much. I tried all you had mentioned above as well and this finally worked! thanks!

Comment: I had site with HTTP and HTTPS binding. For HTTP to work I also had to do that for HTTPS.

Comment: Somehow, this does not work for me. I've been trying to do this trick for Angular applications and React apps, but didn't work. Any other solution?

Comment: @darthVader, make sure that you're clearing the correct domain.

Comment: if hard refresh or clearing cache/cookies is not working for sometimes, try to switch or turn off-on your connection/wifi, there might be an issue in connections

Comment: There is no clear storage on the side menu

Comment: @CoderGautamYT, you are correct. Not sure if they updated the name or I was wrong in the first place. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue. My application was working in Incognito mode and in Firefox but not in Regular Chrome. I even disabled all the extensions but no luck. I eventually cleared the Cached images and files because on developer console I found out that the regular chrome was still picking up the old file due to caching. So as soon as I cleared it, my app showed up like a rocket :)

Comment: Similarly, I had to clear out "Cookies and other site data." My works-only-in-incognito pages now also work in my "normal" Chrome browser. Thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: Did not have to touch cookies. Just cleared the cache.

Comment: I too cleared out BOTH 'cookies & other site data' AND cache, and then it worked. I tried just cache earlier with no luck.

Comment: @bergie3000 this solved my issue as well. Clearing app data (from Development Tools) indeed it's not enough. A delete files and images since the start of times, solved the issue.

Comment: The key for me was to Clear Browsing History > Advanced > Check "Cached Images and Files", then Clear Data for "All time" AND delete all "Cookies and site data" for that domain.

Answer (score 8):

I resolved this unforeseen issue using following steps.

CTRL + SHIFT + DEL > Clear Browsing Data.

1. Cookies and other site data
2. Cached images and files

Comment: I think you're getting downvotes because of your shortcut. Because cleaning cache worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Try removing any non required extension .
Specifically **AdBlock**

I resolved the problem post that.

Since on Incognito , extensions are disabled, hence page run as expected.

Comment: For me, autoplay videos aren't working even though I do have them set to mute. Surprisingly, the autoplay works on incognito. But I've tried disabling all my extensions but I'm still stuck with the same issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: CORS extension doesnt gel with youtube. Try disabling that , or share the list of extensions you are having.

Comment: Widgets in a custom Business Intelligence web app weren't rendering for me under "normal" Chrome, but they were under Incognito and other browsers.  Clearing cookies/cache/site data did not change the behavior, but disabling the LastPass extension did.  So thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately that extension is quite useful, so next on my list is to figure out if there is some other solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is for Chrome Browser.

Open Console  (Ctl+Shift+I) first.

Then under the application tab, you will find some options on the left, find out the application there, you will find it at the top.

There you will find Service Workers.

Under Service Workers, there will be three checkboxes. Select Update on reload checkbox and reload again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after installing React-Sight Extention.
The Page hanged but not in the incognito mode.

- Try deleting any recently added or junk extension.
- Delete your cache.

That worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in chrome, in my case the problem was that I could log in to my university library's website only in incognito mode. After some digging, I figured out that  **Google Translate** extension was set to automatically translate any page. When I turned that off and instead selected never translate that specific page, it started working in the usual mode as well.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Google Translate directly in Chrome. It was the detecting the site(s) in Danish vs English, which seems be a new common problem, and selecting this site is not Danish does nothing, but saying **never translate this site** finally fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather an old issue but still happens. None of the solutions recommended here and there did not solve the issue in my case.
I somehow noticed this is related with a -some kind of- corruption on the user profile.

This is how I solved it:

- Close all Chrome browsers.
- Open a Google page on Chrome.
- Sign-out from Google (rigt click your profile picture on a Google page, not on the Chrome itself), and sign-in.

If this doesn't work:

- Close all Chrome browsers.
- Right click Chrome icon and select Google Chrome.
- Delete your Google profile on the "select your profile" page.
- Close Chrome.
- Open Chrome, sign-in.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer by @ANIK ISLAM SHOJIB
It didn't work, but then I poked around and solved it, so here's another possible solution (worked for a very repetitive chat.openai.com issue):

1. Open Console (Ctrl+Shift+I or F12) first.
2. Go to the the application tab, and in the options on the left look for Service Workers; click on it
3. Click on 'See all registrations'
4. Do a find (Ctrl+F) for the domain name or related domain names, eg 'otisports'
5. When you find it, or something that looks related, hit 'Stop' and 'Unregister', or just 'Unregister'
6. Reload the page.

Note: also try everything else on this page, eg clear cache, data, extensions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above fixed my problem.

I did some digging, and I fixed the issue by changing the names of the classes in the HTML elements that contain **ad** to something else.

Eg: **ad-banner-title** to **banner-title**.

Answer (score -1):

uBlock Origin was the culprit in my case. Once I allowed the site in uBlock Origin, pages loaded correctly in normal Chrome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51999008/2227743